# Declaring Session Max Life Time in htaccess

Tags: php, session

I am wondering whether we can declare [`session.gc_maxlifetime`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime) setting in `.htaccess` for the one particular project instead of whole web server?

If so, how can we do that? Like the following code?

`php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 2000`

I've tried it and it didn't work and also I created a `php.ini` file in the same directory of my project and it didn't work either.

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Yes, session.gc_maxlifetime is a PHP_INI_ALL setting so it can be overidden in .htaccess:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 2000
```

Also make sure that `<Directory>` entry in your Apache configuration supports override:

```
AllowOverride Options
```

It also may be possible that you misunderstood the purpose of this option. This option **will not set the maximum life time of a session**, it will set the amount of time after which the garbage collector will clean the session if it's not valid. This can be determined by a lot of factors, including access times, modification times, other INI options such as [session.gc_probability](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-probability) and [session.gc_divisor](http://ca.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-divisor).

If you want to limit a session life time, use a proper mechanism for that, as described by @Gumbo in [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes/1270960#1270960).

Comment: How to make it overridable? Thanks.

Comment: @Braveyard: It's already in my answer. It's the `AllowOverride` directive. Make sure you read the entire answer, because I still don't think you know what *gc.maxlifetime* really does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I know more about that setting. I like the link by the way.

Comment: That should be an underscore in gc_maxlifetime (took me an while to find this after I copied it)

Comment: this one helped me when im setup domain at hostinger :D

Answer (score 3):

As far I can see, the gc_maxlifetime value can be set anywhere:

http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php

So you could also set it via `ini_set(...)` in a php file included in all your pages.

Anyway, I think your code in the .htaccess should work as well. Maybe you missed something else, for example

```
php_value session.save_path "/PATH/TO/SESSIONS"
```

where PATH/TO/SESSIONS is the path of a folder where you have 777 access permissions.