# PHPMyAdmin automatic session destroy issue

Tags: session, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

I am using Ubuntu server with LAMP and I installed phpMyadmin to manage database. By default phpmyadmin session is destroying after 1440 sec.

I have gone through different online tutorials and forums but no method works.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_LoginCookieValidity):

- Edit the phpMyAdmin `config.inc.php` and add (or edit) the `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity']` directive, for instance `$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 10080`
- Edit the PHP configuration file `php.ini` (making sure to edit the correct one; you can use phpinfo() to locate the correct location) and extend the time for `session.gc_maxlifetime` to at least the same value you used for LoginCookieValidity.

**EDIT**

You don't want to change the `session.gc_maxlifetime` for all of your applications, but there's still hope. Since you are using Apache and if the corresponding `<Directory>` entry in your Apache configuration contains `AllowOverride Options` (or `AllowOverride All`), then you should be able to configure this on a per-application basis to only affect phpMyAdmin.

You'll need to create a .htaccess file in the top level of the phpMyAdmin directory and include a line like:

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10080
```

That will force the modified setting only for that folder (and subdirectories), so as long as it's in your phpMyAdmin folder it will only affect the phpMyAdmin application.

If you prefer, you should be able to create (or modify) an Apache vhost and edit the PHP setting directly in the Apache configuration; the configuration directive would be exactly the same,

```
php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 10080
```

These methods will only work if the `AllowOverride` directive is set to either `All` or `Options`; lesser settings such as `None` will not allow these changes.

[More details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6253756/2385479).

Comment: I appreciate your effort, but I don't want to change default php session time out / cookie destroy time because it will affect all other websites running on my server. I only want to change it for PHPMyAdmin

Comment: Unfortunately the PHP sessions override anything you'd set in phpMyAdmin, for a very good reason -- applications shouldn't be able to set higher resource limits than the system administrator dictates. Depending on your webserver configuration, you may be permitted to set the gc_maxlifetime value just for the phpMyAdmin folder. I'll modify my answer to include more details.

Comment: I am facing the same issue.